# Counting number of entries generated every 30 seconds in R from a csv file

Tags: r, csv

I have the following data in a csv file which I read into my R script.

```
create_date
2016-03-16 11:25:56
2016-03-16 11:25:23
2016-03-16 11:25:12
2016-03-15 17:25:15
```

I want to count the number of entries generated every 30 seconds. e.g. the number of entries generated in `2016-03-16 11:25:01` and `2016-03-16 11:25:30` is `2`. Between `2016-03-16 11:25:31` and `2016-03-16 11:26:00` is `1` and so on.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sequence using `seq.POSIXt` and use it as the defining interval for either `cut.POSIXt` or `findInterval`. This shows how to do it with `findInterval`:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="create_date
2016-03-16 11:25:56
2016-03-16 11:25:23
2016-03-16 11:25:12
2016-03-15 17:25:15", colClasses="POSIXct")

table( findInterval( dat[[1]], 
                     seq( as.POSIXct("2016-03-15 17:23:01"), 
                          as.POSIXct("2016-03-16 11:26:01"), 
                          by="30 sec") )  )
#----------
   5 2165 2166   #  "positions" after 30 second intervals starting "2016-03-15 17:23:01"
   1    2    1
```